# Why is my if condition failing? (reactjs/native with mui)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, if-statement, react-hooks

So I have got this array of string called pages, where the string data is "Music", "Videos" and "Entertainment".

`const pages = ["Music", "Videos", "Entertainment"];`

I want to display them as 3 buttons and I want them to display a specific CSS style when each button is selected. When one button is selected the others must not have that CSS applied. But for some reason my if condition isn't getting hit properly unless clicked multiple time. Could you help me with that?

This is what I have tried:

useState:
`const [selectedMenuItem, setSelectedMenuItem] = React.useState("Music");`

mapping and if condition:

```
{pages.map((page) => (
              (selectedMenuItem === page) ?
                (<Button
                  key={page}
                  onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                  sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
                  className="nav-btn-selected">
                  {page} </Button>)
                :
                (<Button
                  key={page}
                  onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                  sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
                >
                  {page}
                </Button>)
            ))}
```

handleCloseNavMenu just changes the page:

```
const handleCloseNavMenu = (page) => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
    const pageName = page.target.innerText;
    setSelectedMenuItem(pageName);
    navigation.navigate(pageName);
  };
```

The button used is from material ui.

Comment: Where is `setSelectedMenuItem` to set the "active" page button? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] of the code you are working with?

Comment: @DrewReese Okay I will make the edit

Answer (score 0):

The `selectedMenuItem` state should be updated to the currently interacted with page button when it's clicked. I suggest the follow "refactor" to pass the button's `page` value to the `handleCloseNavMenu` click handler to update the state.

```
const handleCloseNavMenu = page => e => {
  setSelectedMenuItem(page); // <-- set active page

  setAnchorElNav(null);
  navigation.navigate(page);
};

...

{pages.map((page) => (
  <Button
    key={page}
    onClick={handleCloseNavMenu(page)} // <-- pass page to handler
    sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
    className={selectedMenuItem === page ? "nav-btn-selected" : ""}
  >
    {page}
  </Button>
)}
```